# Rerouting the wiring under the hood of generator functions and their iterators, where is the iter**able**?

Tags: javascript, iterator, generator, iterable

Digging deep under the hood of GeneratorFunction and Generators. I want to add useful properties to the IteratorResult and possibly to the IteratorResult.value itself. This is all part of a grand scheme to take over the world. But I wonder how I can get a hold of the actual Iterator which the Generator function provides?

First I notice that a generator function itself when being executed has no this value (it's the global object), regardless if it was called first or continues after next():

```
function* range(start = 0, end = Infinity, step = 1) {      
    console.debug("awon", this);
    for(let i = start; Math.sign(step)*(end - i) > 0; i += step) {
        console.debug("tawoo", this);
        i = (yield i)||i; // capricious trickery allowing us to go back or skip with next(arg)
        console.debug("esree", this);
    }
}
```

Now I make myself a useful side-entrance to do all sorts of magic to Generators (like define functions map, reduce, filter, etc.):

```
const Generator_prototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(range.prototype);
```

and with that, here I want to trap the provision of the Iterator object itself:

```
const originalIterate = Generator_prototype[Symbol.iterator];
function iterate() {
    console.log("iter", this);
    const iterator = originalIterate.apply(this);
    iterator.parent = this;
    return iterator;
}
Generator_prototype[Symbol.iterator] = iterate;
```

because, like I said, I want to massage the IterationResult coming from next():

```
const originalNext = Generator_prototype.next;
function next(...args) {
    console.log("next", this);
    let value = originalNext.apply(this, args);
    if(this.decorate)
        value = this.decorate(value); 
    return this.current = value; 
}
Generator_prototype.next = next;
```

And with this:

```
[...range(1,3)]
```

gives the output:

```
iter range {<suspended>}
next range {<suspended>, parent: range}
next range {<suspended>, parent: range, current: {…}}
next range {<suspended>, parent: range, current: {…}}
> (2) [1, 2]
```

so, I never got a hold of the Iterable, only the Iterator. The function [Symbol.iterator] is called on some object, but that object somehow has the thisArg bound to the iterator that it is supposed to return. Notably:

```
iterator = range(1,3)[Symbol.iterator]()
iterator.parent == iterator // > true
```

how can that even happen? I am replacing the @@iterator method with my own, and when it is called it already has an iterator as the thisArg, which is the exact same iterator that I would get if I am asking for the standard iterator by applying the originalIterator to the this? My head is spinning!

How can I get a hold on the iter**able**, not the iter**ator**?

Answer (score 0):

Two main things:

1. Not all iterators **have** an iterable (which is, after all, just an object that implements the `Symbol.iterator` method, directly or indirectly).
2. All built-in iterators use a prototype (which has no public name attached to it, sadly) that makes them iterable by implementating the `Symbol.iterator` method, having it just return `this`. This may seem odd, but it's why we can use `for-of` on built-in iterators (because they're also iterables). This built-in behavior is why you get `iterator.parent === iterator` being `true` in the code at the end of your question.

   Note that this only applies to **built-in** iterators. People can create their own iterators without inheriting from the standard prototype (which is, after all, a pain to get hold of), and sometimes do.

There's no iterable involved in your `range` function or the generator object it returns (other than the generator object itself, because of #2 above).

Your primary goal seems to be to augment or monkey-patch the built-in generator. You can do that via its prototype, but **I wouldn't**. This example doubles the values returned by your `range` generator:

```
// Get the prototype used by built-in generators and its `next` method
const genProto = Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf((function* () {})()));
const defaultGenNext = genProto.next;

// Replace it with our own `next`
genProto.next = function next(...args) {
    console.log(`Args:   ${JSON.stringify(args)}`);
    const result = defaultGenNext.apply(this, args);
    if (typeof result.value === "number") {
        console.log("Doubling");
        result.value *= 2;
    }
    console.log(`Result: ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);
    return result;
};
```

Live Example:

```js
// Get the prototype used by built-in generators and its `next` method
const genProto = Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf((function* () {})()));
const defaultGenNext = genProto.next;

// Replace it with our own `next`
genProto.next = function next(...args) {
    console.log(`Args:   ${JSON.stringify(args)}`);
    const result = defaultGenNext.apply(this, args);
    if (typeof result.value === "number") {
        console.log("Doubling");
        result.value *= 2;
    }
    console.log(`Result: ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);
    return result;
};

// Your `range` function
function* range(start = 0, end = Infinity, step = 1) {
    // console.debug("awon", this);
    for (let i = start; Math.sign(step) * (end - i) > 0; i += step) {
        // console.debug("tawoo", this);
        i = (yield i) || i; // capricious trickery allowing us to go back or skip with next(arg)
        // console.debug("esree", this);
    }
}

// Example
for (const value of range(1, 5)) {
    console.log(value);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Or with a push back to the generator if we want:

```js
// Get the prototype used by built-in generators and its `next` method
const genProto = Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf((function* () {})()));
const defaultGenNext = genProto.next;

// Replace it with our own `next`
genProto.next = function next(...args) {
    console.log(`Args:   ${JSON.stringify(args)}`);
    const result = defaultGenNext.apply(this, args);
    if (typeof result.value === "number") {
        console.log("Doubling");
        result.value *= 2;
    }
    console.log(`Result: ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);
    return result;
};

// Your `range` function
function* range(start = 0, end = Infinity, step = 1) {
    // console.debug("awon", this);
    for (let i = start; Math.sign(step) * (end - i) > 0; i += step) {
        // console.debug("tawoo", this);
        i = (yield i) || i; // capricious trickery allowing us to go back or skip with next(arg)
        // console.debug("esree", this);
    }
}

// Example
let flag = true;
let result;
let it = range(1, 5);
while (!result?.done) {
    if (result) {
        console.log(result.value);
    }
    let param;
    if (flag && result && result.value === 4) {
        param = 1;
        flag = false;
    }
    result = it.next(param);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Doubling is obviously just an example, and note that you have access to the value passed to `next` as well as to the result object it returns.

**Again, though, I wouldn't do that,** for at least two reasons:

1. Mucking about with the built-in prototypes usually doesn't end well.
2. Not all generators inherit from the generator prototype.

After all, generation (like iteration) is *just a protocol*. That means you can implement it with your own code, completely bypassing any of the built-in stuff.

What I'd do instead is write a function to wrap around the generator you want to transform. For instance, here's a simple doubler that doesn't support pushing back:

```
function* double(target) {
    for (const value of target) {
        yield value * 2;
    }
}
```

Then just use `double(range(1, 5))` or whatever instead of `range(1, 5)`.

Live Example:

```js
// Your `range` function
function* range(start = 0, end = Infinity, step = 1) {
    // console.debug("awon", this);
    for (let i = start; Math.sign(step) * (end - i) > 0; i += step) {
        // console.debug("tawoo", this);
        i = (yield i) || i; // capricious trickery allowing us to go back or skip with next(arg)
        // console.debug("esree", this);
    }
}

function* double(target) {
    for (const value of target) {
        yield value * 2;
    }
}

// Example
for (const value of double(range(1, 5))) {
    console.log(value);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Or you can write it to support the pushback:

```js
// Your `range` function
function* range(start = 0, end = Infinity, step = 1) {
    // console.debug("awon", this);
    for (let i = start; Math.sign(step) * (end - i) > 0; i += step) {
        // console.debug("tawoo", this);
        i = (yield i) || i; // capricious trickery allowing us to go back or skip with next(arg)
        // console.debug("esree", this);
    }
}

function* double(target) {
    const it = target[Symbol.iterator]();
    let lastArg;
    let result;
    while (!(result = lastArg === undefined ? it.next() : it.next(lastArg)).done) {
        lastArg = yield result.value * 2;
    }
}

// Example
let flag = true;
let result;
let it = double(range(1, 5));
while (!result?.done) {
    if (result) {
        console.log(result.value);
    }
    let param;
    if (flag && result && result.value === 4) {
        param = 1;
        flag = false;
    }
    result = it.next(param);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```